# Extract layers from PDF file to HTML

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF file, containing layers.

For example, on some pages, there are graphs, with additional data displayed on top of that graph, when clicking (layers).

Now I need to try to fetch all these layers out of the PDF file, or to be precise, I need ALL the data from that PDF file, including layers. The pdf file contains javascript to show/hide the layers when appropriate.

What is the best approach? Is there any tool that actually works for my intentions? Or should I write something myself? (If this is possible ofcourse).

Edit:

Here you can download the PDF file:
http://www.2shared.com/document/IutUfDfr/OR_erasmus.html

The password for viewing is: erasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there are any tools per se but if you cannot find those you might do the following:

- for each combination of on/off layers that you are interested in walk all pages and collect the content streams. Tokenize those and cut out the content you do not want to see (the commands you need to monitor to determine this are BDC and EMC). Save the stream again with the clipped content (naturally save the result in different files). You need something to read the PDF object structure and update some objects (there are lot's of libraries for that), plus you need tobe able to parse the content streams.

Now you will have a set of PDF files without layers (optional content) for which there are plenty tools to render to HTML etc.

Note: optional content <--> layer switches in the PDF viewer usually are 1:1 but the standard supports a full n:m mapping. I would concentrate on the real optional content blocks that can be turned on/off to keep things simple.

Comment: This looks out of my league. I'm trying something with an external PDF lib (itextsharp), I'm now at the part where I'm walking over every page, collecting the stuff of that page in a PdfDictionary. Then I'm kinda trapped ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tool to extract images and text from even locked pdfs

http://download.cnet.com/Able2Extract/3000-2079_4-10249654.html

I use it myself sometimes and it has the ability to convert to HTML

Comment: I tried that, however, upon opening the PDF file I get an unknown encryption used error...

Comment: I'll add the PDF so you can see it what type it is.